# PGP on Dark Net Markets: What threats does it control?

Tags: pgp

Most Dark Net Markets (Agora, Nucleus, etc.) recommend that customers use PGP when communicating with vendors, particularly when sending their address. The vendor's public key is presented publicly on their DNM profile.

What threats does this control? And to what extent? For example:

- Compromised marketplace
- Compromised seller account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always in information security, different scenarios and attack vectors must be considered.

### New Communication

Encryption with unverified keys taken from the marketplace **can definitely *not* protect against a compromised marketplace** -- obviously, in a compromised marketplace, the keys could have been exchanged. You might realize when keys change for the same seller, though. Pretty much the same applies to a **compromised seller account, where the key could be changed to one in control of the attacker**.

In the end, there is not a lot of protection when the marketplace or an account on there is compromised, especially if you get in touch with the other side for the first time.

**It might help, though if there's a problem in-between, during transmission**, when the attacker has no control over the listed keys. For example unencrypted data sent by accident or software issues, or other problems with the transport security, when the message's contents are still encrypted themselves.

### Old (Earlier) Communication

**More important, message encryption will make *old* communication safer.** Whoever gets hold of the encrypted messages because the seller's account or whole marketplace was compromised, will *not* be able to read the message's plain text. Depending on the security measures taken by the recipient (like offline keys, and passphrases to encrypt the keys), even a compromised or seized computer will not reveal the message's contents.

### Adding Signatures

Finally, this might not only help at securing privacy of the communication, but also **assure the identities of the communication partners if signatures are used**. Given an account is compromised after some time, you would not be able to realize this. If messages are not only encrypted, but also signed, you could realize the sender is somebody else -- everybody could encrypt using your public key, but as long as the real account owner's key was not compromised, they cannot impersonate him.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks. I'm wondering if PGP can help with a compromised marketplace - if there was some external monitoring for changed PGP keys. It would certainly force hackers to be less stealthy.

Comment: You might monitor keys by trusting them locally. If there is a changed key, you would be notified about missing trust.

Answer (score 2):

Since PGP is end-to-end encryption it at least prevents the transport of the mail. This is contrary to the usual hop-by-hop encryption with TLS where the mail is available unencrypted at each mail server in the delivery chain.

Apart from that the mail might also be still encrypted in the inbox of the recipient and the outbox of the sender so that they are still protected even if the sender or recipient is compromised - as long as the private part of the recipients PGP key is not known to the attacker. But once the key is known all old and future communications to the same recipient (with the same key) can be decrypted.

Getting a mail signed with PGP might also help to make sure that you are talking to the right person. On the other hand signing might be dangerous because once the recipient got successfully attacked you will have a hard time to dispute the origin of a mail if you signed it using your own PGP key. And since you are asking about the dark market you would probably wish to dispute the origin successfully.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with non-repudiation being the last thing you want! I think most DNMs advocate PGP with encryption only, not signing.